# Shelosha Vachamishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred fifty-three?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

153 is the number of pesukim in Parshas Vayishlach, according to our mesorah that ויהי בשכן... ויהיו בני יעקב שנים עשר is one verse. (The masoretic note at the end of the parshah that says 154 follows the variant opinion which divides it into two verses.)

Answer (score 2):

**בצלאל = 153**

**הפסח = 153**